# App config different project best practice

Tags: .net, configuration

By default the app.config that gets loaded is the one in the project that contains the entry point to the application.

Now the data access code cares about the RDBMS (Oracle, SQL etc). If I store the connection string in the DAL project instead of the start up project, it would remove the dependency between the DAL and the start up project. But from experience I know that the connection string is always stored in the start up project.

Whats the recommended project (start up of data access layer) to store the connection string? If it is the start up project, is the resulting dependency between the start up and DAL acceptable?

Comment: Why would you need something like this? What problem with the `app.config` file would this solve?

Comment: @Oded: Whats the recommended place to store the config file that contains the connection string? The entry project or the data access layer? Since the code in the the data access cares about the specific RDBMS , making connection string a part of the data access project seemed to make sense to me.

Comment: Standard location is the [`connectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.100).aspx) configuration section of the entry project. It is also the recommended location. A data access layer should not care about _which_ database/server it needs to use.

Comment: You can store that config anywhere you like though. For instance, on my work project we have a config project and our entry-point App.config just refs these external files for all the diff config sections we need.

Comment: @Blam - Not true. Please explain why you think these should be different?

Comment: @Blam - And a different provider for Oracle. So? The connection string configuration should still be in `app.config` in either case.

Comment: @Blam - Fair enough. My comment was about connection strings, as this is the focus of the question. Though data access layers can be written to be database agnostic.

Comment: @Oded I deleted my comments as they were of little value

Comment: @Oded: When you sayy "data access layers can be written to be database agnostic. " do you mean by using Inversion of Control?

Comment: @developer747 - Yes, and, at least with .NET, with using the data base classes (so `DbConnection` instead of `SqlDbConnection` or `OracleDbConnection`).

Answer (score 0):

Hello: If you are looking to decouple the presentation from the repository, then you would want (need) to store such info in the repository/DAL project.  So it isn't true that the start-up project always holds such information.  Using Entity Framework, for example, you will find the app.config's version of a connection string in this layer (normally the repository or DAL).

It is very common to store the connection string of databases in the web.config file, but this is only because it is common to have a one-to-one relationship between your presentation layer to a repository.  I tend to use the app.config file of the either the data or service layer and don't need to include my presentation layer when performing unit testing.